# Find a Lipschitz constant for a quadratic function restricted to a ball

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Fix $a$ in ${\mathbb R}^d$ and $b$ in ${\mathbb R}$, consider $x$ in ${\mathbb R}^d$ where $\|x\| \le B$. Is the following function Lipschitz? (and if so, what is a Lipschitz constant?)
$$f(x) =  (\langle a, x \rangle + b)^2$$

Answer (score 3):

$Df(x) = 2(\langle a, x \rangle + b) a^T$, and
$\|Df(x)\| \le 2(|b|+\|a\| \|x\|) \|a\| \le 2(|b|+B\|a\|) \|a\|$.

Then the mean value theorem shows that
$f$  is Lipschitz with rank $2(|b|+B\|a\|) \|a\|$.